# How to package CMake Module in NativeSDK?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I am trying to install a set of CMake utilty functions under `/usr/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/MYMODULES/useful.cmake` within a Yocto build.

Here is my current (sanitized) recipe (call it `my-useful-modules.bb`)

```
SECTION = "devel"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

inherit cmake

EXTERNALSRC := "path/to/source/code"

do_compile() {
     :
}

FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/cmake-3.4/Modules/MYMODULES/*"
BBCLASSEXTEND = "nativesdk"
```

The configure and install tasks work fine, and if I look under `image` in `tmp/work/...`, I see the full tree (including all my host directories as expected).

But I keep getting the following error

> ERROR: nativesdk-my-useful-modules-1.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue:
>   nativesdk-my-useful-modules: Files/directories were installed but not
>   shipped in any package:

Followed by a long list of files which basically includes everything under `image`.

These modules need to be available both in the native sysroot during the build, and in the standard SDK built with populate_sdk.

Which package should I be specifying with `FILES_${PN}` to get them packaged?

I'd also appreciate knowing how to either avoid specifying the cmake version in the `FILES` statement, or get it from the build system.

Answer (score 0):

Updating FILES_${PN} will resolve your error and also there is no need to provide cmake version in this case.

```
FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/*"
```

Comment: Nope - already tried that :( That's why I added the full path. Still get the same error with "bitbake nativesdk-my-useful-modules". I *think* it's something to do with SDKMACHINE and HOSTMACHINE being different. I also tried `"${D}${libdir}/"`

Comment: did you check in ${D}/${libdir} that useful.cmake is being installed properly ?

Comment: yeah. As I said under the image drectory in `tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-pokysdk-linux/nativesdk-my-useful-modules/1.0-r0` I see `/home/kdopen/build/build//tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/MYMODULES/useful.cmake`

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I had also tried `"${D}${datadir}/*"`, not `"${D}{libdir}"`